# How to configure Open JDK 11 in STS?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, openjdk-11

How to configure Open JDK-11 in STS(3.5)? When i go to window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's and provide OPENJDKHomeFolder\bin, i get a message "Target is not a JDK root. javaexecutable not found".

I could not find any references/documentation to this problem. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Which exact version of STS do you use? Do you really mean version 3.5, which is from 2014. That version doesn't support JDK11, as far as I remember. Using the latest version of Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse, configuring an OpenJDK 11 should be no problem.

Comment: Apologies. I used sts-4.8.0.RELEASE. @MartinLippert - I had to do the below as well to make it work - In sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\SpringToolSuite4.ini file, i had to add the below in the very first line: -vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies. I used sts-4.8.0.RELEASE. @MartinLippert - I had to do the below as well to make it work -
In sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\SpringToolSuite4.ini file, i had to add the below in the very first line in addition to pointing to home folder as mentioned by @Kris
-vm
OpenJDK11\openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javaw.exe (absolute path)

Note: Adding the above anywhere else in ini file will not work. Why? Note sure!

Ironical that, i could not find any refences to this problem. Had to spent 1 day to figure out this. Anyways got it working and hope it will be useful for others.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working and thanks for sharing this here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think are doing it almost correctly. Instead of pointing to the 'bin' folder instead point it to the 'root' folder of the JVM installation, as the message suggests.

So in other words do not point at the 'bin' folder but at the parent of that folder.